# Flutter Simulator > Android studio SDK Manager > Command line tools installation issue

Tags: java, flutter, macos, android-studio, installation

I just started to learn Flutter. And getting an error to install Android studio on my Mac. (Actually, installation was done and the app looks fine. But `flutter doctor` returns issue)

##### My environment

macOS, M2, Sonoma 14.2.1

##### Issue

I got below by `flutter doctor` command:

```
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.
```

##### What I tried

1. Installed Flutter by brew
2. Installed the Android studio from its homepage (download and run the dmg file)
3. Ran Android studio and installed SDKs by its Wizard
4. At this point, flutter doctor started to return the message I pasted above.
5. Because I couldn't find the 'SDK Manager' section in its 'settings' window (It seems the Android studio for Mac UI was changed... I searched some documents but they were not matched with my screen. not sure...), I downloaded 'Command line tools only' zip file from Android studio homepage.
6. and ran this `~/Downloads/cmdline-tools/bin/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
7. It said it requires Java, so I installed it.
8. After installing Java, above command returned `'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/sdklib/tool/sdkmanager/SdkManagerCli has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0'`
9. I tried to find the way to download lower version sdkmanager or upper version Java, but couldn't.
10. I re-installed the android-studio by brew, but the result was same.
11. I moved the downloaded cmdline-tools to library/Android/ and ran the command again but no luck.

##### Question

What can I try next?

The iOS simulator is working fine but I want to check Android simulator together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps to solve this Android Studio issue of Yours.

1. goto Android studio and click 3dots on rigt corener top
2. open SDK manager
3. On SDK manager click on second tab "SDK TOOLs"
4. uninstall & Download command line tools

STEP IMAGES
[image]
[image]

I HOPE THIS WILL HELP YOU. IF IT DON;T WORK TEXT BACK I WILL HELP YOU TO INSTALL FLUTTER properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot Raj Jani! It has been solved!! Let me change the question title to include the SDK manager  Hope you have a good day!